# Find actual value of SyntaxError exception python

Tags: python

I'm trying to evaluate python code stored in a string using the ast library, however when accessing the message attribute of the SyntaxException error produced, I can only print the reference to the object and not the actual value. How do I print this value?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ast

def is_valid_python(code):
    try:
         ast.parse(code)
    except SyntaxError:
         return str(SyntaxError.message)
    return True

code = 'print("hello"")'

print(is_valid_python(code))
```

and the message printed is:

```
<attribute 'message' of 'exceptions.BaseException' objects>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the generic SyntaxError class' message attribute, not the one from the actual exception that was thrown.

Try

```
except SyntaxError as syntax_error:
    return syntax_error.message
```

Note that it's a bit strange to have a function that returns True on success, or a string on failure.